# packet socket not receiving data

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have the following C code that is supposed to await **any** packet on ethernet device `eth0`, including `IPv6` multicast messages.

I am using a `packet(7)` socket here, as my underlying code is handling the layers. Hence, I want to receive all packets on that socket.

The communication to the other host is established via two `IPv6` multicast messages back and forth and a subsequent `TCP`-based communication.

```c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 0);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror("cannot open socket");
    }

    struct sockaddr_ll sll;
    memset(&sll, 0, sizeof(sll));
    sll.sll_family   = AF_PACKET;
    sll.sll_ifindex  = if_nametoindex("eth0");
    sll.sll_protocol = ETH_P_ALL;

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&sll, sizeof(sll)) < 0)
    {
        perror("cannot bind socket to device");
        return 1;
    }

    while(1) {
        char *recvBuf[1518];
        struct sockaddr_ll saddr;
        socklen_t saddr_size = sizeof(saddr);

        size_t len = recvfrom(fd, recvBuf, 1518, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&saddr, &saddr_size);

        // PRINTOUT HERE
    }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile on my debian machine like that:

```sh
gcc my_sniffer.c -o test.bin
setcap 'cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+ep' ./test.bin
./test.bin
```

The binary starts up. However, no packet is received.

Running `tcpdump -i eth0 -w test.pcap`, yields in a received `IPv6` multicast message.

What am I missing here? Is the code off? Wrong socket in use?

Comment: `char *recvBuf[1518];` should be `char recvBuf[1518];` but I don't think that's your problem. You also didn't check for errors from recvfrom

Comment: Thanks! Updated the code accordingly. However, not the issue why I do not receive anything...

Comment: What happens if you change 0 to htons(ETH_P_ALL) when calling `socket`?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried that before as well. Yields in no result...

Comment: What happens if you do that and also don't bind it?

Comment: Silly question: are you sure one of those packets comes in when your program is running?

Comment: @user253751 that actually worked. So removing the `bind` as well as setting to `htons(ETH_P_ALL)` is the solution... THANKS!

Comment: but then you are getting packets from all interfaces...

Comment: oh, is `sll.sll_protocol = ETH_P_ALL;` a mistake? Forgot `htons`

Comment: Exactly that was the problem. `sll.sll_protocol = ETH_P_ALL;` had to be removed.

Comment: So the bind is actually fine. I also need it if I want to reply/send back a multicast.

Comment: It's probably a mistake because you forgot htons. When it's zero then binding doesn't set the protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
sll.sll_protocol = ETH_P_ALL;
```

you forgot to use `htons`